# How do I separate camera and GUI in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, camera, encapsulation

I have an app that uses the Android camera.

I want to implement something like a `CameraManager` class, that will deal with everything that has to do with the camera, opening, closing, camera parameters and a frame buffer.

The thing is, I want to separate `CameraManager` from the GUI, but in Android, the camera seems to be inseparable from the GUI, because you need a `surfaceView` to get previews.

One idea I had, is have the `CameraManager` return a `surfaceView` to the GUI manager, after `CameraManager` initialization, and have the GUI manager handle everything after that. But, it's not separated enough because Camera manager is still touching GUI stuff.

Any thoughts on how can I manage to maximize this encapsulation?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the suggested Google method and implement views in XML. Create two custom surfaceviews (In my case one was a GLSurfaceView, and the other was a SurfaceView). One view implements the camera and the second can handle a GUI with graphics and or buttons. The key is creating a custom GLSurfaceView and SurfaceView in XML that uses the class names of the extended SurfaceView and GLSurfaceView. Also you must make the GUI view transparent. Please note that graphics are drawn in the MainRenderer class which is not included here. Please be aware the code below has problems with OpenGL context loss, which I am working to fix. The code shown below should be enough to help you get going but it won't work on it's own without mods... Most of the code below is derived from Googles OpenGl Tutorial

[OpenGl ES 1.0 Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html)

with my own mods to get everything separated.

Here is the XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >                         
<com.zypath.opengltest.MainSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/glSurfaceView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />                                       
<com.zypath.opengltest.CameraView
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/mangle"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/mangle"
         android:textColor="@color/mcolor" />                       
</LinearLayout>
```

Part of Main Code:

```
  public class Main extends Activity {
  ...


   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // When working with the camera, it's useful to stick to one orientation.
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    //Set full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Substantiate surfaces
    cameraView = (CameraView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    mGLView = (MainSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glSurfaceView);        

    //Initialize TextViews
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mangle);
    txtView.setText("Angle: " + String.valueOf(mAngle)); 


}
```

Part of Custom MainSurfaceView

```
  public class MainSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
...

//Constructor
public MainSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {       
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;

    mRenderer = new MainRenderer();
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); 

    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);    

    setZOrderOnTop(true);

    //Render only when there is a change
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);         
}

//TouchEvent handler
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    .....

    return true;
}
```

Part of Camera Code:

```
  public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
  ...
private Camera camera;
SurfaceHolder holder;

public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // We're implementing the Callback interface and want to get notified
    // about certain surface events.
    getHolder().addCallback( this );
    // We're changing the surface to a PUSH surface, meaning we're receiving
    // all buffer data from another component - the camera, in this case.
    getHolder().setType( SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS );
}

public void surfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder holder ) {
    // Once the surface is created, simply open a handle to the camera hardware.
    camera = Camera.open();
}

public void surfaceChanged( SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height ) {

        camera.setPreviewDisplay( holder );

    camera.startPreview();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass a surface view as a parameter to the  CameraManager constructor. 
I hope you make the manager open source :)

edit :
this is what I used in an old project  (sharing  is a good thing :P )

```
CameraView

package at.fhb.triangulate.gui;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources.Theme;
import android.view.View;
import at.fhb.triangulate.main.TriangulateMain;


/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;

    public CameraView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            // TODO: add more exception handling logic here
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera = null;
    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
       // parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

}
```

Comment: your solution is not perfect either.. because the camera manager will still have to implement the SurfaceHolder.Callback.. or if i make the gui implement it, then i'll have to make the gui touch the camera. why the hell did they design it like that?! btw, it won't be open source unfortunately :P

Comment: im not 100% sure if  its possible (its some time  I have done something with camera)  cant you  also pass the  callback  as  parameter ? or  create a new callback interface.  This new callback could be implemented  from the gui  called from the original callback which does all the camera touching code ?